# Vue.js & Rails: How can I stop HTML from rendering before Vue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js

I'm having a problem with implementing Vue into my Rails app. I have to refresh my page in order for the Vue elements to load. For instance, if my element is defined as:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#page',
        data: {
            question: "content"
      }
    })
})
```

The content won't load into the following HTML tag upon first loading. I have to reload the page:

```
<div id="page">
  <div id="bold-font">{{question}}</div><br/>
  <%= text_area 'table', 'column' %>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you get errors in browser console?

Comment: The typo is only in the question. I edited it. The tags all match up in my code. It functions, I just have to reload the page and need it to load immediately.

Comment: Your Rails template is generated dynamically ? If yes Vue will not render it's data if the `#page` is not already rendered.

Comment: I'm a Rails novice and am sort of jumping into the deep-end with it, would you be able to point me in the direction of any documentation that would explain how to generate the template non-dynamically so that Vue knows what to expect before the page loads?

Comment: Oh, to answer the earlier answer; no, I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: You can try the vueonrails project. Simply run `rails new app -m http://vueonrails.com/vue` and then scaffold a component is simply `rails g vue component`

Comment: I just tried it on my end and it works. I used the scaffold project from Vue on Rails. I suspect you did not have <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>` in your application.html.erb?